# iterating for loop to form a custom html table

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I want to form a custom html table in php from a db query. My sql query is

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data','td');
    $query->join('drone','dg','dg.tid = td.tid ');
    $query->fields('td',array('tid','name'));
    $query->fields('dg',array('drone_name'));
    $result=$query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

The data returned by the query looks like:

```
Drone Name        Drone Assigned
Huge                DJI
Huge                Parrot
Beginner            Skydio
Beginner            Insitu
Beginner            EHANG
```

```
 $drone_table='<br/>
  <table id =  width="40%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1" align="center";">
    <th>Drone Name</th> 
    <th>Drones Assigned</th>';
```

I wrote a for loop statement

```
foreach ($result as $ts){

      $drones_assigned[] = $ts->name;
      $drn_name = $ts->drone_name;      

    $com_arr = implode(",",$drone_assigned);

    $drone_table.='<tr>
    <td>'.$drn_name.'</td>
    <td>'.$com_arr.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

This doesnt form the table I want. t forms a table a combination of all the drones assigned and one drone.

I want something like

```
Drone Name           Drone Assigned
     Huge                 DJI, Parrot
     Beginner             Skydio,Insitu,EHANG
```

But I am getting

```
Drone Name        Drone Assigned
    Beginner             DJI, Parrot, Skydio,Insitu,EHANG
```

Comment: Can you represent a sample of the data returned by the query?
I also recommend using more readable variables in the future because your code is unreadable honestly.

Comment: Why not show us the array?????

Comment: @RaedYakoubi I have edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: So you just need to print the query in a table, for instance if there is 3 _Beginner_ drones you will just have to print one `Beginner` in the "Drone Name" cell, and all of the assigned drones in the other ones, is that right?

Comment: @RaedYakoubi Yes

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is one way to do that, i will be using the [alternative `foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) syntax in the HTML code because i personally think it is more readable this way.

1. First we have this database query result which i assigned to a *PHP* array:

```php
$results = [
    ['name' => 'Huge', 'assigned' => 'DJI'],
    ['name' => 'Huge', 'assigned' => 'Parrot'],
    ['name' => 'Beginner', 'assigned' => 'Skydio'],
    ['name' => 'Beginner', 'assigned' => 'Insitu'],
    ['name' => 'Beginner', 'assigned' => 'EHANG'],
];
```

2. Now we have to get the assigned *drones* for each *drone name*, we'll go with a `foreach` loop that will generate an array of the form `$array['drone_name'] = ['assigned_drones', '.....']`:

```php
$drones = [];

foreach ($results as $drone) {
    if (!array_key_exists($drone['name'], $drones)) {
        $drones[$drone['name']] = [];
    }

    $drones[$drone['name']][] = $drone['assigned'];
}
```

3. Lastly we'll print out these values inside of an HTML table using the `foreach` loop (alternative syntax):

```php
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Drone Name</th>
        <th>Assigned Drones</th>
        <?php foreach ($drones as $name => $assigned): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo implode(',', $assigned); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chage your sql query to get formatted results like this :

```
$result = db_query("SELECT  dg.drone_name , GROUP_CONCAT(td.name) FROM taxonomy_term_data td
                        INNER JOIN drone dg ON dg.tid = td.tid GROUP BY dg.drone_name")->fetchAllKeyed();


foreach ($result as $drone_name => $drones_assigned){

    $drone_table.='<tr>
    <td>'.$drone_name.'</td>
    <td>'.$drones_assigned.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Also you can take a look to theme table rendering by drupal to create html table easyly https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7.x

Comment: Thanks @Fky, This is what I wanted. An sql query!!